# How can I put a marker on the top when using mapbox on android

Tags: android, mapbox, markers

I am using map box android SDK 4.2.1
One of my page may have many markers (like 99+ markers) I want to put the marker on the top when user clicks it, is there a way to make it ? like modify its "z" property;

[image]

I add markers like this:

[image]

thanks

Comment: Use the array size as z-index.

Comment: One of the saddest thing in MapBox it so counter intuitive like setting the pivot point of a pin to center, z-index is not even on the API. It so frustrating to use. I guess we are extreme cases where we are the only people that needs it. But JS has it. Its API is so fragmented across the board one platform is capable of setting anchor points, z-index while other platform doesn't even have it(Android).